# Как запустить новое окно в onPostExecute, AsyncTask?

Tags: android

Я пытаюсь сделать вход в серверное андроид приложение. У меня есть класс, который делает работу на "заднем" плане, сравнивает информацию из текстовых полей окна с БД(логин, пароль). И в onPostExecute я хочу открыть новое окно. И я не совсем представляю как это сделать.
Пока что это выглядит так:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if(result.toString().equals("0"))
        {
            alertDialog.setMessage("Все хорошо");
            alertDialog.show();
        }
        else{
            alertDialog.setMessage("Неверные данные");
            alertDialog.show();
        }
}
```

И вот вместо алерт окна "Все хорошо", хочу открыть новое окно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все достаточно просто:

```
  protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        if (result.equals("login success")){
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, OnGame.class));
        }else {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

И самое главное правило, не забудьте добавить активность в манифест.